# From right to left in textBox (asp.net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

How do you achieve this. and i set some text inside the textbox. i want it to be lower in opacity and disappear whenever the user clicks on the textbox to begin typing (like in iphone interface). How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ajax water mark** control and **jquery autoclear plugin**

Answer (score 2):

In html5 a new attribute introduced [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp), you can make use of this attribute

In aspx markup your TextBox is

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then in Page_Load set the attribute.

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "you faded text like in iphone");
```

**Edit 1:**

You are right, for right to left text you need to add another [dir attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twe16yc2.aspx) on TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" dir="rtl"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: your tip, didnt owrk. text ddoesnt appear

Comment: @Dmitry, you need to add `dir` attribute to achieve right to left text.

Answer (score 1):

For the watermark there is the [HTML5 placeholder attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) or you could also use a [jquery watermark plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) if your site is not yet HTML5. For right to left you may take a look at the [following article](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do it using java script. See the code below:

1. set a default text for your textbox.
2. for clearing the textbox call the following function on textbox **onblur** event

   ```
   function ClearSearchText() {
       var searchUserName = document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>');         

           if (searchUserName.value = searchUserName.defaultValue) 
           {
               searchUserName.value = "";
           }


       return false;
   }
   ```
3. for setting call the following function on textbox **onFocus** event

   ```
       function SetSearchText() {

       var searchUserName = document.getElementById('<%=txtBoxID.ClientID%>');


           if (searchUserName.value == "") 
           {
               searchUserName.value = searchUserName.defaultValue;
           }
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```
4. do the search in button postback after checking the default text and also set the textBoxID.Text="your default text".

hope this will help..

Comment: i havent got onfocus and onblur event. it is asp.net control :(

Comment: see the "onblur" and "onfocus" events won't appear as an attribute within the asp.net control, but you can use it and will work for sure. see my asp.net contol below where i used it with success:  <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxID" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="input-box" onfocus="ClearSearchText()" onblur="SetSearchText()"></asp:TextBox>